# Rails+Paperclip+Imagemagick+Windows 7 => got error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, imagemagick, paperclip

I have installed paperclip and imagemagick on RoR 3.2 on Windows 7 64 bit.

My model looks like that:

```
  has_attached_file :sample_file, 
    :styles => { :large => '0x200>' },
    :default_style => :large,
    :url => "/uploads/images/baget/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/images/baget/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

And when I uploading image, it loads once, and when I want to load another image, I get this:

```
Errno::EINVAL in BagetsController#create
Invalid argument - ruby_setenv
```

And than - this:

```
Internal Server Error
Invalid argument - <STDOUT>
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-02-22) at localhost:3000
```

Next, only restaring WEBRick helps, but again - only one time.

BUT! If change my model to only this:

```
has_attached_file :sample_file
```

then I get all working. So, I think that this probably cause from ImageMagick. Or Maybe Win7 is lagging? I dont know. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The weak place is Win7. Changed to ubuntu and all work perfect